# Building multipart file payload content correctly

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, multipartform-data

I'm sending a binary file via multipart POST request in the following way:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
body = '--' + boundary + '\r\n'
             + 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; '
             + 'filename="temp.bin"\r\n'
             + 'Content-type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n'
             + encryptedFileContent + '\r\n'
             + '--' + boundary + '--';
xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:999/some/path", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary="+boundary);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
        console.log("File uploaded!");
}
xhr.send(body);
```

I'm sending it within a chrome packaged app, and the reason I'm sending the file in this way is because initially the file is read from local filesystem via `FileReader`, and then it gets encrypted before being submitted.
`encryptedFileContent` is built in the following way:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e) {
     var plainArray = Array.apply([], new Int8Array(e.target.result));
     var encryptedArray = encrypt(plainArray);
     var encryptedFileContent="";
     for (var i=0; i<encryptedArray.length; i++) { 
          encryptedFileContent+=String.fromCharCode(encryptedArray[i]) 
     }
}
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

Debugging, I can see that the `encryptedArray` contains the following values:

```
[ 70, -21, -15, ... ]
```

On the server side, when the array is read, I would expect to see the same data, but instead I see:

```
[ -17, -66, -112, ... ]
```

Looks like the way I build the payload for the binary file is incorrect. Is `String.fromCharCode` the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the byte array received on the server was different is that the payload is converted to unicode and encoded to utf-8.
In order to send data without any conversion, you should send data as binary, as described here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FXMLHttpRequest%2FUsing_XMLHttpRequest#Submitting_forms_and_uploading_files

```
if (!XMLHttpRequest.prototype.sendAsBinary) {
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.sendAsBinary = function(sData) {
        var nBytes = sData.length, ui8Data = new Uint8Array(nBytes);
        for (var nIdx = 0; nIdx < nBytes; nIdx++) {
            ui8Data[nIdx] = sData.charCodeAt(nIdx) & 0xff;
        }
        /* send as ArrayBufferView...: */
        this.send(ui8Data);
        /* ...or as ArrayBuffer (legacy)...: this.send(ui8Data.buffer); */
    };
}
```